# How can I use KNN, Random Forest models in Pytorch?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pytorch

This may seem like a X Y problem, but initially I had huge data and I was not able to train in given resources (RAM problem). So I thought I could use `batch` feature of `Pytorch`. But I want to use Methods like KNN, Random Forest, Clustering except Deep Learning. So is it possible or can I use scikit libraries in Pytorch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

### Update

Currently, there are some `sklearn` alternatives utilizing GPU, most prominent being `cuML` (link [here](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml)) provided by rapidsai.

### Previous answer

I would **advise against** using `PyTorch` solely for the purpose of using batches.

**Argumentation goes as follows**:

1. `scikit-learn` [has docs about scaling](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/scaling_strategies.html) where one can find [MiniBatchKMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans) and there are other options like `partial_fit` method or `warm_start` arguments (as is the case with RandomForest, [check this approach](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327335/batch-learning-w-random-forest-sklearn)).
2. KNN cannot be easily used without hand-made implementation with disk caching as it stores whole dataset in memory (and you lack RAM). This approach would be horribly inefficient either way, **do not** try.
3. You most probably will not be able to create algorithms on-par with those from scikit (at least not solo and not without considerable amount of work). Your best bet is to go with quite battle-tested solutions (even though it's still `0.2x` currently). It should be possible to get some speed improvements through [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) but that's beside the scope of this question. Maybe you could utilize CUDA for different algorithms but it's even more non-trivial task.

All in all `PyTorch` is suited for deep learning computations with heavy CUDA usage. If you need neural networks, this framework is one of the best out there, otherwise go with something like `sklearn` or [other frameworks allowing incremental training](https://dask-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/incremental.html#scikit-learn-s-partial-fit). You can always bridge those two easily with `numpy()` and few other  calls in `pytorch`.

**EDIT:** I have found KNN implementation possibly suiting your requirements [in this github repository](https://github.com/spotify/annoy)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible - but you would have to implement them yourself. Pytorch has the primitives for these methods because it implements its own kind of [tensors](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=device#torch.Tensor.to) and what not; however, the library only provides an abstraction layer for Deep Learning methods. For example, a very naive `KNN` implementation (of a matrix produced from the vector distance current point) would be

```
def KNN(X, k):
    X = X.float()
    mat_square = torch.mm(mat, mat.t())
    diag = torch.diagonal(mat_square)
    diag = diag.expand_as(mat_square)
    dist_mat = diag + diag.t() - 2*mat_square
    dist_col = dist_mat[-1, :-1]
    val, index = dist_col.topk(k, largest=False, sorted=True)
    return val, index
```

You should use `scikit-learn` if you want easy, out of the box solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented nn, knn and kmeans only using PyTorch. You can find the implementations on this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/JosueCom/7e89afc7f30761022d7747a501260fe3). It is a bit long to post here. But you can use it by doing:

```py
import torch as th
from clustering import KNN

data = th.Tensor([[1, 1], [0.88, 0.90], [-1, -1], [-1, -0.88]])
labels = th.LongTensor([3, 3, 5, 5])
test = th.Tensor([[-0.5, -0.5], [0.88, 0.88]])

knn = KNN(data, labels)
knn(test) ## returns tensor([5, 3])
```

Comment: The data doesn't have to be 2D it can be any size

Comment: Nooo the gist doesn't exist anymore!